# Can someone recommend good resources to self study physics please?

Tags: particle-physics

I have a goal to educate myself up to the current level of knowledge we possess about the universe.

I've tried textbooks, wikipedia, lectures, but i find each of them fundamentally flawed in different ways.

Textbooks tend to be incredibly bloated, and I become unable to "see the forest for the trees"
Wikipedia seems to be too technical/mathematically rigorous for my level of understanding
Lectures feel very time consuming and i dont really feel as though i get a structured sense of  how everything fits together.

I feel as though all mathematical and physical concepts can be explained in simple terms, yet i cant find resources which present concepts like this.

I don't want explanations that are completely dumbed down or necessarily lacking in math, but i would prefer explanations which give math intuition and take time to explain what the variables and symbols mean in laymen's terms.

If anyone knows any resources similar to what i described, or has any advice it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I should also mention that i had been referred to Hooft's outline of learning, as seen here:
http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html#ssphysics
Which i find to be a trememndous help, but I'm still struggling as to the ideal places to find clear resources in regards to these subjects.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of our book recommendations meta-question because (despite the name) the questions listed there will also contain links to other resources.

Comment: I was writing an answer but ruefully your question is closed. I am about to complete my answer so if you are interested in my answer tell me where I can send it to you. I also studied through self study. Although I do not have the whole knowledge of the universe but I have school level knowledge.

Comment: "I" is always capital.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Pronouns